# Get the lists of things to do from tripadvisor

Tags: python, web-scraping, tripadvisor

how to get the 'things to do' list? I am new to webscraping and i don't know how to loop through each page to get the href of all 'things to do'?tell me where i am doing wrong?Any help would be highly apreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



offset = 0
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g255057-Activities-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#ATTRACTION_LIST_CONTENTS'
urls = []
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")


for link in soup.find_all('a', {'last'}):
    page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
    last_offset = int(page_number) * 30
    print('last offset:', last_offset)


for offset in range(0, last_offset, 30):
    print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')
    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g255057-oa' + str(offset) + '-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#ATTRACTION_LIST_CONTENTS'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
        iurl='https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057' + link.get('href')
        print(iurl)
```

Basically i want the href of each 'things to do'.
      My desired output for 'things to do' is:

```
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057-d3377852-Reviews-Weston_Park-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057-d591972-Reviews-Canberra_Museum_and_Gallery-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057-d312426-Reviews-Lanyon_Homestead-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g255057-d296666-Reviews-Australian_National_University-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
```

Like in below example i used this code for getting the href of each restaurant in canberra city
my code for restauranr which works perfectly is:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen



with requests.Session() as session:
    for offset in range(0, 1050, 30):
        url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g255057-oa{0}-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'.format(offset)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).content, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.select('a.property_title'):
            iurl = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/' + link.get('href')
            print(iurl)
```

the output of restaurant code is:

```
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g255057-d1054676-Reviews-Lanterne_Rooms-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g255057-d755055-Reviews-Courgette_Restaurant-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g255057-d6893178-Reviews-Pomegranate-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
   https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g255057-d7262443-Reviews-Les_Bistronomes-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory.html
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Try passing a dict in `soup.find_all` , eg : `soup.find_all('a', { 'k' : 'v' })`

Comment: u mean that i have to use soup.find_all('a',{'class':'listing_element'}) like this?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Can you update your code and give an example of  the output you get and what the desired output should be ?

Comment: @t.m.adam  i update the code kindly help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , it's not that hard, you just have to know which tags to use .
Let me explain with this example :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/'  ## we need this to join the links later ##
main_page = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g255057-Activities-oa{}-Canberra_Australian_Capital_Territory-Hotels.html#ATTRACTION_LIST_CONTENTS'
links = []

## get the initial page to find the number of pages ##
r = requests.get(main_page.format(0))  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
## select the last page from the list of pages ('a', {'class':'pageNum taLnk'}) ##
last_page = max([ int(page.get('data-offset')) for page in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'pageNum taLnk'}) ])

## now iterate over that range (first page, last page, number of links), and extract the links from each page ##
for i in range(0, last_page + 30, 30):
    page = main_page.format(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(page).text, "html.parser") ## get the next page and parse it with BeautifulSoup ##  
    ## get the hrefs from ('div', {'class':'listing_title'}), and join them with base_url to make the links ##
    links += [ base_url + link.find('a').get('href') for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'listing_title'}) ]

for link in links : 
    print(link)
```

That gives us 8 pages and 212 links in total ( 30 on each page, 2 on the last ) .
I hope this clears things up a bit

Comment: You 're right , I forgot to get the next pages .  I updated the code , try again

Comment: You are very welcome , i hope i helped you understand the process

Comment: yeah it helped alot :) ty